# What's the difference between "лежит на столе" and "стоит на столе"?

Tags: выбор-слова, словоупотребление

Can anyone explain the difference between the following sentences:

1. *"Чашка лежит на столе"* vs. *"Чашка стоит на столе"*
2. *"Мяч лежит на столе"* vs. *"Мяч стоит на столе"*
3. *"Лэптоп лежит на столе"* vs. *"Лэптоп стоит на столе"*

When I should use the first one and when the second one?

Comment: My apologies for off topic, but: http://entre-2-mondes.livejournal.com/77158.html

Comment: One more thing: russians very rarely say "лэптоп". "Ноутбук" is a much more common word.

Comment: "Лежит" means "lays". "Стоит" means "stays". We say object "stays" if it has highest possible organized position. Otherwise it "lays". The analogy is human: efforts are required to stay, but no effort means falling down and lay.  So it is some sort of animacy in language. A cup can both lay on the table if it is on it's side, or stay if it is put correctly. Sometimes there is no correct usage, so as for laptop. So you can say anyway you like.

Comment: There's probably only one way to remember this - to learn by hard what is commonly used and what's not. See example by @Evgraf to try to understand. It's a comic text for native-speakers. There are no obvious rules for that and too many exceptions, BUT: vertical object usually "stands", horizontal object "is laid down", that's why a book stands on a shelf but lays down on a table. And the difference between to положить (put horizontal) or поставить (put vertical). Second kind of rule is something on a floor may "lay down" because it can be thrown there. What's thrown usually is "laid down".

Comment: I suppose we will say the laptop lays on a table if it is closed and stays on a table if it is open

Answer (score 39):

It's not as easy as it seems. In fact, it's very complicated.

1. **Objects that look like a rectangular cuboid** (e.g. books)

They «stand» when their long part is placed vertically and «lie» when their long part is placed horizontally.

> Книга стоит на полке.
> Книга лежит на столе.

2. **Objects that can be in their proper position**

If they are in their proper position, they «stand» (e.g. an opened laptop, a flower in a vase). If they are folded or placed wrong, they «lie».

> Цветы стоят в вазе.
> Цветок лежит на диване.

3. **Objects that have only one possible position**

Mostly they always «lie». But sometimes they may «stand» (I don't know when) but there are few examples:

> Коробка лежит на полу.
> Нож лежит на полу.
> Нож лежит на столе.

But attention:

> Коробка стоит на столе.
> Чашка/стакан стоит на столе

Comment: nice answer. Welcome aboard )))

Comment: I would say, this depends on how large the box is. If it is large, it stands (even on the floor), if it is small, it lies (even on the table).

Comment: huh, what about parrot, for example? =) Correct way to say: `Попугай сидит на столе`. Not `стоит`, and, well, not `лежит` (i'm talking about a parrot that feels good)

Comment: Чашка стоит на столе потому что у нее есть неправильная позиция (на боку). И коробка что на полу, что на столе, все же стоит, а не лежит, как мне кажется. и у нее опять же есть неправильная позиция (есть крышка или какой-то ее аналог).

Comment: Коробка лежит на полу, потому что её бросили на пол. Если коробку аккуратно поставить на пол, она будет стоять.

Answer (score 18):

There is no simple rule about using “лежит на столе” and “стоит на столе”. We even have a joke

> Перед нами стол. На столе стакан и вилка. Что они делают? Стакан
>   стоит, а вилка лежит. Если мы воткнем вилку в столешницу, вилка будет
>   стоять. То есть стоят вертикальные предметы, а лежат горизонтальные?
>   Добавляем на стол тарелку и сковороду. Они вроде горизонтальные, но на
>   столе стоят. Теперь положим тарелку в сковородку. Там она лежит, а
>   ведь на столе стояла. Может быть, стоят предметы готовые к
>   использованию? Нет, вилка–то готова была, когда лежала.
>
> Теперь на стол залезает кошка. Она может стоять, сидеть и лежать.
>   Если в плане стояния и лежания она как–то лезет в логику
>   "вертикальный–горизонтальный", то сидение — это новое свойство. Сидит
>   она на попе. Теперь на стол села птичка. Она на столе сидит, но сидит
>   на ногах, а не на попе. Хотя вроде бы должна стоять. Но стоять она не
>   может вовсе. Но если мы убьём бедную птичку и сделаем чучело, оно
>   будет на столе стоять. Может показаться, что сидение — атрибут живого,
>   но сапог на ноге тоже сидит, хотя он не живой и не имеет попы. Так
>   что, поди ж пойми, что стоит, что лежит, а что сидит.
>
> А мы ещё удивляемся, что иностранцы считают наш язык сложным и
>   сравнивают с китайским.

Comment: Никогда бы не сказал, что вилка, воткнутая в столешницу, _стоит на столе_. По-моему, она _торчи́т_.

Comment: Отличие очень простое: если у предмета есть какая-то подставка, и он прочно на ней находится, то предмет стоит. Если нет - он лежит, вот и всё. У вилки подставки нет, поэтому её как ни размещай, она будет только лежать. А стакан может как стоять, так и лежать.

Comment: @Malcolm тарелка на столе **стоит,** в коробке **лежит.**  Даже если в обоих случаях тарелка находится в горизонтальном положении. Если вилку  **положить** в стакан, то она будет **стоять.**

Comment: @Vitaly Верно, потому что если тарелка лежит в коробке, она может находиться в любом положении и вовсе не обязательно прочно находится на подставке. И вилка в стакан всё же не кладётся, а ставится, и стакан как бы становится её подставкой, потому что она теперь стоит _в_ стакане _на_ столе. Уж точно никто не скажет, что вилка стоит на стакане или просто на столе, потому что она и стакан стали составным предметом. Если положить стакан, то положится и вилка вместе с ним.

Answer (score 11):

Easy going explanation for you:

[image]

Comment: Please do not give a one-link answer. Take time to include an explanation.

Comment: and what about cubic items? )))

Comment: and what about a plate or a dish?

Comment: поздно но... and what about a ball?

Comment: I have frequently heard this answer from native speakers, but the way the actually decide is much more complicated. The most obvious example is "Тарелке стоит на столе."

Answer (score 9):

1. Never "Чашка лежит на столе" exept where a cup is upset on side
2. Never "Мяч стоит на столе".
3. Both are fine.

Objects with base: cup, bottle, flask, bowl, jar, dish, pan, pot — always "стоит".

Objects without base: pen, book, sheet of paper, spoon, fork, knife — always "лежит".

Flower in a vase — "стоит".
Flower laid on the table (on its side) — "лежит".

Answer (score 6):

вещи имеющие основание и стоящие на нём - "стоят".
иначе - "лежат".
пример: "шкаф стоит на полу", но положенный на бок (не находится на основании) - "шкаф лежит на полу".

вещи не имеющие основания - "лежат".
Но размещенные в вертикальной плоскости они - "стоят".
пример: "карандаш лежит на столе", но если поставить его на кончик, то "карандаш стоит на столе".
Плоские вещи не имеют основания и к ним применяется правило вещей без основания:
"книга лежит на столе", но если её поставить на бок, то "стоит на столе".

Ноутбук в закрытом состоянии вещь плоская, поэтому он "лежит". Но в открытом состоянии у него появляется основание, поэтому он "стоит".
Круглые вещи всегда "лежат".

Comment: В таком случае, почему коробка _стоит_ на столе, но _лежит_ на полу?

Comment: всё-таки и про открытый ноутбук можно сказать, что он лежит (но только если он не используется).

Comment: The best answer!

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that everything long — *стоит*; everything horizontally-oriented (like laptop) — *лежит*. In some situations you need to remember word choice.

1. One can say *чашка лежит на столе*, when it is lying on its side:

   [image: Чашка лежит на столе]

   In all other cases *чашка стоит*.
2. A ball always *лежит на столе*. You cannot say *стоит* about a ball. It would mean that a ball is something steady, which it is not.
3. A closed laptop always *лежит на столе*, unless it is positioned on its side (by some miracle). If a laptop is open, it *стоит*.

Comment: Лэптоп может стоять, если он открыт. "Чей это лэптоп стоит на столе?"

Comment: I'd say, that "Лэптоп лежит" is a more rare form, but can imply that the laptop is not being open and used but we're just indicating the location, like in "- Где мой лэптоп? - На столе лежит."

Comment: I would also say «чашка лежит» when it is hidden away, say in a dishwasher, or packed in a box, even if it happens to be in а vertical position. It is also normal to ask «где у тебя лежат чашки?» implying they can be found in some cupboard, not on display.

Answer (score 2):

1. Both are correct, but the first if the cup is in horizontal position.
2. "Мяч лежит на столе" only.
3. "Лэптоп лежит на столе" if it's closed. "Лэптоп стоит на столе" if it's open.

Comment: cups quite rare are in in horizontal position )))

Comment: yes, but it's possible ;

Answer (score 2):

I think this should be explained to a foreigner in a different way than explaining horizontal and vertical positions. A non-Russian speaker should imagine that the object that is positioned on the table is in fact a creature (animate object).

English has the verbs *to stand* and *to lie* but they normally only used with people or mammals. The person should think that if the book would be a creature and it was in its current position, what would he/she say about this creature: *stands* or *lies*. If *stands* would be more appropriate for creature - say *stands* for the book, say *lies* otherwise.

As always, there will be exceptions from the rule which need to be memorized.

Let's look at the тарелка стоит на столе. The plate is ready to serve you - to hold the food. Of course, it is standing. :-) If the plates are put in the box for moving, for example, they will be *положены (lying)*. I.e. ***стоять* и *лежать* also has the connotation of being in a working position or in an out-of-work position.**

Also, it seems the story of how difficult it is to explain to English speaker the difference between *stand* and *lie* for objects is a bit exaggerated. It is kind of "new urban myth" - a nice story to retell and have fun. In fact, in English *standing* and *lying* is also used for objects (but not usually *stand* and *lie*). You cannot say: `CN tower stands in downtown Toronto.` But you can say: `CN tower is the world's tallest free standing tower.` The same for lying: `He checked the pile of dirty cloths lying on the floor.` So, it is quite clear to the English speaker that *stands/стоит* denotes a vertical position, and *lies/лежит* denotes a horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the explanation which we used in an introductory course. One of the things we emphasized was that you cannot treat Russian words as one-for-one replacements for English words. You have to treat them as words in their own right with their own definitions. Therefore we defined the verbs used in these expressions:

лежать--to lie fallen or stretched out. A knife can лежит and will unless you stand it up inside a glass or stick it into the table. I drinking glass will лежит if you knock it over. A dinner plate cannot лежит because it is not tall enough to fall over!

стоять--to stand in a vertical position, possibly on some kind of foot. A boy can стоит on his feet. Drinking glasses стоят on their bottoms which are a kind of foot. Dinner plates стоят too!

сидеть--to “sit” in the sense of occupying a sunk down but still upright position. A boy can сидит on a table or chair, but a drinking glass cannot because it has no legs to fold.

These definitions are intended as a starting point for beginners. They obviously will not cover all cases where one must choose between стоять, лежать, and сидеть.

We also prepared a video demonstration which you can see here:
http://www.readyrussian.org/Videos/Motion%20and%20Location/

Answer (score 0):

In Russian the position of an object must be made explicit. You can't simply say *"The book is on the table."*, instead, you need to specify whether the book is in horizontal or vertical position. This applies not only to the "state" verb, but also the "movement" one. When you talk about "putting something", you must specify how in those cases too.

This is a simple table that exemplifies it:

```
              State      | Movement (to put something in that position)
             -----------------------------------
              НСВ        | НСВ         СВ
Vertical      Стоять     | Ставить     Поставить
Horizontal    Лежать     | Класть      Положить
Hanging       Висеть     | Вешать      Повесить

Sitting       Сидеть
```

Some examples:

> **Книга лежит на столе.**
>   *The book is on the table (horizontal).*
>
> **Я положил книгу на стол.**
>   *I put the book on the table (horizontal).*
>
> **Я повесил куртку.**
>   *I hung the jacket (hanging).*

Comment: > In Russian the position of an object must be made explicit. You can't simply say "The book is on the table." 

Well, it is not correct, here is a counterexample:  "Книга на столе". In addition to "стоять" and "лежать", a book can also "находиться на столе" when its exact state is not important.

Comment: @DenisMakerenko Good counterexamples. Alenanno is putting it too strong when he says "must be made explicit". It would be more accurate to say that in Russian there is a strong tendency to make these things explicit. In English we say what and where things are. In Russian we say what they do.

Comment: Uhm interesting point, I'll update the answer asap.